# Filter dictionary in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to filter a `dictionary` within a `list`. My data looks like this:

```
[('John', 'Samantha', {'source': 'family'}),
 ('John', 'Jill', {'source': 'work'})]
```

I need to filter records with `source=family`, I tried the following but didn't work:

```
expectedResult = [i for i in my_list if i['source'] == 'family']
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the desired result?

Comment: `item` isn't what you named the loop variable, and isn't itself a dictionary... You have a list of *tuples*, the third value in which is a dictionary.

Comment: What is `item`, how does it relate to `i` in the `for` loop? You have tuples, so `i[-1]` or `i[2]` is the dictionary in each item in the list, you want to address *that reference* if you want to do anything with the dictionary.

Comment: We also have to assume that example list given is assigned to the name `my_list`, but that's a smaller problem.

Comment: Next question: are your data entries *always* tuples of 3 elements, with two strings and a dictionary? Does the dictionary *always* have a `'source'` key? Please be explicit.

Comment: yes the dictionary always has a 'source' key

Answer (score 3):

In your list comprehension, `i` is one of the tuples, so `('John', 'Samantha', {'source': 'family'})` or `('John', 'Jill', {'source': 'work'})`. That's not a dictionary, so you can't treat it like one!

If your tuples are always consisting of 3 elements and the 3rd element is a dictionary with a `source` key, use:

```
[i for i in my_list if i[2]['source'] == 'family']
```

You'll have to add some more code if any of those assumptions do not hold. For example, if the dictionary is always there but the `'source'` key could be missing, you could use `dict.get()` to return a default when the key is not there:

```
[i for i in my_list if i[2].get('source') == 'family']
```

If the length of the tuple can vary, but the dictionary is always the last element, you can use a negative index:

```
[i for i in my_list if i[-1]['source'] == 'family']
```

etc. As a programmer, you always have to check for such assumptions.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept *one* of the answers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-) The choice is yours, pick the one that you feel helped you the most (and not picking any is also valid).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following solution based on comprehensions, assuming only that the dictionaries always have a key named 'source' as you said in comments:

```
my_list = [('John', 'Samantha', {'source': 'family'}),
           ('John', 'Jill', {'source': 'work'}),
           ('Mary', 'Joseph', {'source': 'family'})]

# Keep only elements including a dictionary with key = "source" and value = "family" 
my_filtered_list = [t for t in my_list if any((isinstance(i,dict) and i['source'] == 'family') for i in t)]
print(my_filtered_list)  # [('John', 'Samantha', {'source': 'family'}), ('Mary', 'Joseph', {'source': 'family'})]

# If needed: remove the dictionary from the remaining elements
my_filtered_list = [tuple(i for i in t if not isinstance(i,dict)) for t in my_filtered_list]
print(my_filtered_list)  # [('John', 'Samantha'), ('Mary', 'Joseph')]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter function to filter lists

```
>>> li = [('John', 'Samantha', {'source': 'family'}),
...  ('John', 'Jill', {'source': 'work'})]
>>>
>>> filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x[2]['source'] == 'family', li))
>>>
>>> filtered
[('John', 'Samantha', {'source': 'family'})]
>>>
```

Comment: Why the switch to filter? What was wrong with using a list comprehension? The issue was not with how they were looping, only how they are addressing the individual elements while filtering. You corrected that but you are not stating your assumptions (that the 3rd element is always a dictionary) nor do you make it explicit that that was the problem in the first place.

Comment: Yes i guess my code may have done overfitting due to less data